# What is considered canon for Pirates of the Caribbean?

Tags: canon, pirates-of-the-caribbean

The [*Pirates of the Caribbean* franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean) is comprised of five feature films and one short film, two book series for young readers and one novel written for adults, a number of video games, and of course the theme park attractions.

Most of these are shown in this [timeline](https://web.archive.org/web/20190213005143/http://thetimelinesite.com/pirates-of-the-caribbean) (preserved on the Internet Archive).

**Which of these are considered canon?**

Are there different levels of canon, where a lower level source can be overridden by a higher level source?

[image: An opened hatch with a cannon pointing out, pirates Pintel and Ragetti on either side, Pintel pointing and screaming]
*A canon cannon*

Comment: There were also comics.

Comment: @Gallifreyan And (at least some of) the comics are considered non-canon, AFAIK, because the later movies contradict them.

Comment: The Pirates wikia says [some works are non-canon](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Non-canon_articles) (as decided by the author or licensees, according to the articles' disclaimer) and also lists [some articles of ambiguous canonicity](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Articles_of_ambiguous_canonicity), although I don't find any definition or reasoning behind this on the wikia.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an authoritative source of canon in the POTC universe